# jQuery Filter - How to set a different active button, other than "All"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple jQuery filter set up. I'm trying to reset the active class to cat-sun, instead of cat-all. I've changed up the jQuery to assign the active class to cat-sun, instead of cat-all. I'm missing something somewhere because it's not working.

```js
var filterActive;

function filterCategory(category) {
    if (filterActive != category) {
        
        // reset results list
        $('.filter-cat-results .f-cat').removeClass('active');
        
        // elements to be filtered
        $('.filter-cat-results .f-cat')
            .filter('[data-cat="' + category + '"]')
            .addClass('active');
        
        // reset active filter
        filterActive = category;
        $('.filtering button').removeClass('active');
    }
}

$('.f-cat').addClass('active');

$('.filtering button').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('cat-sun')) {
        $('.filter-cat-results .f-cat').addClass('active');
        filterActive = 'cat-sun';
        $('.filtering button').removeClass('active');
    } else {
        filterCategory($(this).attr('data-cat'));
    }
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
button {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 .5em .5em -10px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

button.cat-sun {
  background: #ff4136;
}
button.cat-sun:hover {
  background: #e90d00;
}

button.cat-mon {
  background: #2ecc40;
}
button.cat-mon:hover {
  background: #208e2c;
}

button.cat-tue {
  background: #0074d9;
}
button.cat-tue:hover {
  background: #004b8d;
}

button.cat-wed {
  background: magenta;
}
button.cat-wed:hover {
  background: darkmagenta;
}

button.cat-all {
  background: #333;
}
button.cat-all:hover {
  background: #0d0d0d;
}

.f-cat {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
}

.cat-sun {
  background: #ff4136;
}

.cat-mon {
  background: #2ecc40;
}

.cat-tue {
  background: #0074d9;
}

.cat-wed {
    background: magenta;
}

.row .col {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}
.row .col.active {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.65s ease forwards;
  animation: fadeIn 0.65s ease forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <h2>jQuery Button Filtering</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container filtering">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-filter-cat">
        <li><button class="cat-all" data-cat="cat-all">All Days</button></li>
        <li><button class="cat-sun active" data-cat="cat-sun">Sunday</button></li>
        <li><button class="cat-mon" data-cat="cat-mon">Monday</button></li>
        <li><button class="cat-tue" data-cat="cat-tue">Tuesday</button></li>
        <li><button class="cat-wed" data-cat="cat-wed">Wednesday</button></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="row filter-cat-results">
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-sun" data-cat="cat-sun">Sunday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-sun" data-cat="cat-sun">Sunday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-wed" data-cat="cat-wed">Wednesday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-mon" data-cat="cat-mon">Monday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-tue" data-cat="cat-tue">Tuesday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-sun" data-cat="cat-sun">Sunday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-mon" data-cat="cat-mon">Monday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-wed" data-cat="cat-wed">Wednesday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-mon" data-cat="cat-mon">Monday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-tue" data-cat="cat-tue">Tuesday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-mon" data-cat="cat-mon">Monday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-tue" data-cat="cat-tue">Tuesday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-wed" data-cat="cat-wed">Wednesday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-sun" data-cat="cat-sun">Sunday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-tue" data-cat="cat-tue">Tuesday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-wed" data-cat="cat-wed">Wednesday</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your button handler is treating `cat-sun` as the special case, instead of `cat-all`. Replace the two occurrences of `cat-sun` with `cat-all` and it works fine. (btw, you can use `$(...).data('cat')` to read and set `data-` attributes.)

Comment: Let me rephrase - I want `cat-sun` to be the default. `cat-all` will remain as an option, but Sunday needs to be the default.

Comment: Let *me* rephrase: do you want the sunday button to display only sundays? Or do you want the sunday button to wrongly display *all days*, while the "All days" button does nothing? Because your code does the latter. Fix that first, then worry about the default (just call the Sunday button's click handler at the start: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/k4jLuwdf/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were setting all the ".f cat" elements "active". So all the elements are showing up by default. And also I don't understand the reason behind "if else" block in your click handler  Here is the modified code. Hope this serves your purpose.

```js
var filterActive;
var _defaultFilter = "cat-sun";

function filterCategory(category) {
    if (filterActive != category) {
        
        // reset results list
        $('.filter-cat-results .f-cat').removeClass('active');
        
        // elements to be filtered
        if( category == "cat-all") {
         $('.filter-cat-results .f-cat').addClass("active");
        } else {
         $('.filter-cat-results .f-cat')
            .filter('[data-cat="' + category + '"]')
            .addClass('active');
        }
        // reset active filter
        filterActive = category;
        $('.filtering button').removeClass('active');
    }
}

//$('.f-cat').addClass('active');

$(".f-cat[data-cat="+_defaultFilter+"]").addClass('active');
filterActive = _defaultFilter;

$('.filtering button').click(function() {   
    filterCategory($(this).attr('data-cat'));    
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
button {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 .5em .5em -10px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

button.cat-sun {
  background: #ff4136;
}
button.cat-sun:hover {
  background: #e90d00;
}

button.cat-mon {
  background: #2ecc40;
}
button.cat-mon:hover {
  background: #208e2c;
}

button.cat-tue {
  background: #0074d9;
}
button.cat-tue:hover {
  background: #004b8d;
}

button.cat-wed {
  background: magenta;
}
button.cat-wed:hover {
  background: darkmagenta;
}

button.cat-all {
  background: #333;
}
button.cat-all:hover {
  background: #0d0d0d;
}

.f-cat {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
}

.cat-sun {
  background: #ff4136;
}

.cat-mon {
  background: #2ecc40;
}

.cat-tue {
  background: #0074d9;
}

.cat-wed {
    background: magenta;
}

.row .col {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}
.row .col.active {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.65s ease forwards;
  animation: fadeIn 0.65s ease forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <h2>jQuery Button Filtering</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container filtering">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-filter-cat">
        <li><button class="cat-all" data-cat="cat-all">All Days</button></li>
        <li><button class="cat-sun active" data-cat="cat-sun">Sunday</button></li>
        <li><button class="cat-mon" data-cat="cat-mon">Monday</button></li>
        <li><button class="cat-tue" data-cat="cat-tue">Tuesday</button></li>
        <li><button class="cat-wed" data-cat="cat-wed">Wednesday</button></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="row filter-cat-results">
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-sun" data-cat="cat-sun">Sunday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-sun" data-cat="cat-sun">Sunday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-wed" data-cat="cat-wed">Wednesday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-mon" data-cat="cat-mon">Monday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-tue" data-cat="cat-tue">Tuesday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-sun" data-cat="cat-sun">Sunday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-mon" data-cat="cat-mon">Monday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-wed" data-cat="cat-wed">Wednesday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-mon" data-cat="cat-mon">Monday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-tue" data-cat="cat-tue">Tuesday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-mon" data-cat="cat-mon">Monday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-tue" data-cat="cat-tue">Tuesday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-wed" data-cat="cat-wed">Wednesday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-sun" data-cat="cat-sun">Sunday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-tue" data-cat="cat-tue">Tuesday</div>
        <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6 f-cat cat-wed" data-cat="cat-wed">Wednesday</div>
    </div>
</div>
```